# In how many ways can you bet thirteen different football matches to get exactly 12 right

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

**In how many ways can you bet thirteen different football matches to get exactly 12 wins?**

My attempt

First I notice that there is only $1$ way to bet $13$ different matches to get $13$ wins.

Second, I notice that ther are $3^{13}$ ways to bet $13$ different football matches.

Now, I refrase the question: In how many ways can you bet thirteen different football matches to get exactly $1$ loss?

This gives
$$\binom{13}{1}\cdot2^{1} = \frac{13!}{1! (12)!}\cdot2=13\cdot2=26.$$
Now, assume you want to know in how many ways you can bet thirteen different football matches to get exactly $2$ losses?
Well that would give $$\binom{13}{2}\cdot2^{2} = \frac{13!}{2! (11)!}\cdot4=78\cdot4=312.$$

So, the general formula is $\binom{n}{r}\cdot2^{r} = \frac{n!}{r! (n-r)!}\cdot2^{r}.$
On the other hand, with $13$ matches to be bet on and exactly $1$ to be a loss, I could argue that the loosing match could be chosen in $13$ different ways, and that each match only have $2$ possible choices, as
$$13\cdot2=26.$$ This result corresponds well to the answer above.

With the same argument, with $13$ matches to be bet on and exactly $2$ to be a losses I could argue that the first loosing match could be chosen in $13$ different ways, and the second loosing match in $12$ different ways, and that each match only have $2$ possible choices, as $$13\cdot12\cdot2=312.$$

Even this result correspond to the answer above.

But, when repeating the calculation for the choice of $3$ lost games (corresponding to $10$ wins), the magic disappears:

$$\binom{13}{3}\cdot2^{3} = \frac{13!}{3! (10)!}\cdot8=286\cdot8=2288\ne13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot2=3432.$$

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: What magic are you referring to, the formula seems correct to me?

Comment: (This might be horribly wrong)

I think the second what you count(the one without the combination symbol) double counts some of the outcomes. For example, losing the bet on game_3, game_2, game_1 is the same as losing the bet on game_2, game_3, game_1. As a result, you need to divide by 3!

Comment: Also, you need to multiply by $2^{\text{bets lost}}$ because each of the games has two ways to lose.

Comment: The reason why it worked for the case of two bets lost is because they canceled each other out. That is, $(\frac{1}{2!} * 2^2)$ is still 2

Comment: @BigBear: Fantastic, thanks alot. Assume I do not know the nPr, by stricly looking at the betting koupong, how could I reason to come to the correct conclusion?

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @BigBear: Ok, now I see it. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Pablo What do you mean by koupong? Sorry I didn't see the rest of the earlier comment

Comment: @BigBear: coupons, 1 coupon concists of 13 matches. I misspelled.

Comment: Idk if this answers your questions, but I thought it it like this: If I want to lose exactly k times of 13 bets: $\\$


13*12*...*(13-k+1) = sequences of the games I could lose.


I divide that by (k!) so I make sure that game_1,game_2 = game_2, game_1 


And then I multiply that by $2^{\text{bets lost}}$

Comment: @BigBear: Brilliant! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of $13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 2$ is wrong two ways.  The first three factors are the number of ways to choose the games you get wrong, but you count each order differently.  If the games you lose are $ABC$ you are counting $CBA$ as different.  That is the factor $3!$ between $13 \choose 3$ and $13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 $.  Then, having chosen the three games to lose, there are two ways to lose each, so the final factor should be $2^3$.  The two combine to multiply $3432$ by $\frac 46$, getting $2288$.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer.